# AutoMapper and inheritance - How to Map?

Tags: c#, inheritance, automapper

Have this scenario:

```
public class Base {  public string Name; }

public Class ClassA :Base {  public int32 Number;  }

public Class ClassB :Base { public string Description;}

public Class DTO {
  public string Name;
  public int32 Number;
  public string Description;
}
```

I have an `IList<Base>`
my maps are:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IList<Base>, IList<DTO>>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Number, opt => opt.Ignore())
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.Ignore());

AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<ClassA, DTo>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.Ignore());

AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<ClassB, DTO>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Number, opt => opt.Ignore())

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); //Is OK!
```

But Properties that are in ClassA Or ClassB are not mapped when I do this :

```
IList<DTO>= AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IList<Base>,IList<DTO>>(baseList);
```

How can I do to map properties that are defined in `ClasA` and `ClassB`

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You will need to create DTO classes that match your domain classes like this:

```
public class DTO
{
    public string Name;
}

public class DTO_A : DTO
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class DTO_B : DTO
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

You then need to change your mappings to this:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Base, DTO>()
            .Include<ClassA, DTO_A>()
            .Include<ClassB, DTO_B>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<ClassA, DTO_A>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<ClassB, DTO_B>();

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Once this is done, then the following will work:

```
        var baseList = new List<Base>
        {
            new Base {Name = "Base"},
            new ClassA {Name = "ClassA", Number = 1},
            new ClassB {Name = "ClassB", Description = "Desc"},
        };

        var test = Mapper.Map<IList<Base>,IList<DTO>>(baseList);
        Console.WriteLine(test[0].Name);
        Console.WriteLine(test[1].Name);
        Console.WriteLine(((DTO_A)test[1]).Number);
        Console.WriteLine(test[2].Name);
        Console.WriteLine(((DTO_B)test[2]).Description);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Unfortunately this does mean that you have an unwanted cast, but I don't think there's much that you can do about that.

Comment: No worries Gringo, glad it helped.

Answer (score 10):

At least with recent Automapper versions (>2.0?) your code is okay if you remove the `IList<>`:s of your first `CreateMap` statement<sup>1</sup>. And you don't have to create specific DTO classes as @Simon suggests in another answer (unless that's what you want).

But to be specific about the inheritance and to avoid redundant mapping clauses when you extend the base class you can specify the inheritance by using the `.Include` method. So, if you create your mappings like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Base, DTO>()
    .Include<ClassA, DTO>()
    .Include<ClassB, DTO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Number, opt => opt.Ignore());

Mapper.CreateMap<ClassA, DTO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.Ignore());

Mapper.CreateMap<ClassB, DTO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Number, opt => opt.Ignore());

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); //Is OK!
```

then you can do this:

```
var baseList = new List<Base>
{
    new Base {Name = "Base"},
    new ClassA {Name = "ClassA", Number = 1},
    new ClassB {Name = "ClassB", Description = "Desc"},
};

var test = Mapper.Map<IList<Base>, IList<DTO>>(baseList);
Console.WriteLine(test[0].Name);
Console.WriteLine(test[1].Name);
Console.WriteLine((test[1]).Number);
Console.WriteLine(test[2].Name);
Console.WriteLine((test[2]).Description);
Console.ReadLine();
```

(Note that you don't have to map IList specifically. Automapper handles this for you.)
[See this article](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance) about `.Include`.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Actually I wonder if the code compiled as written in the question?</sub>

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you answer. Yes, it compiles

Comment: This should be actually valid answer for inheritance mapping. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need both the `.Include`s and the individual mappings from `ClassA` and `ClassB`?

Answer (score 5):

Following on from Eugene Gorbovoy's answer, if you're using profiles to configure your AutoMapper, you need to use a `TypeConverter`.

Create a new `TypeConverter` like this

```
    public class NumberConverter : ITypeConverter<DTO, NumberBase>
    {
        public NumberBase Convert(DTO source, NumberBase destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            if (source.Id % 2 == 0)
            {
                return context.Mapper.Map<EvenNumber>(source);
            }
            else
            {
                return context.Mapper.Map<OddNumber>(source);
            }
        }
    }
```

and replace the `ConvertUsing` line in his example with

```
  expression.CreateMap<DTO, NumberBase>()
            .ConvertUsing(new NumberConverter());
```

Comment: Perfect answer - just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I did this to solve the problem

```
IList<DTO> list1 = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IList<ClassA>,IList<DTO>>(baseList.OfType<ClassA>().ToList());

IList<DTO> list2 = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IList<ClassB>,IList<DTO>>(baseList.OfType<ClassB>().ToList());

list = list1.Union(list2);

persons.OfType<T>().ToList()
```

Must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario you have to use IMappingExpression.ConvertUsing method.
By using it you can provide appropriate type for newly created object.
Please, look at my example (pretty well fit your scenario):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using AutoMapper;

namespace ConsoleApplication19
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //mapping
            Mapper.Initialize(expression =>
            {
                expression.CreateMap<DTO, NumberBase>()
                    .ForMember(@class => @class.IdOnlyInDestination,
                        configurationExpression => configurationExpression.MapFrom(dto => dto.Id))
                    .ConvertUsing(dto =>//here is the function that creates appropriate object
                    {
                        if (dto.Id%2 == 0) return Mapper.Map<EvenNumber>(dto);
                        return Mapper.Map<OddNumber>(dto);
                    });

                expression.CreateMap<DTO, OddNumber>()
                    .IncludeBase<DTO, NumberBase>();

                expression.CreateMap<DTO, EvenNumber>()
                    .IncludeBase<DTO, NumberBase>();
            });

            //initial data
            var arrayDto = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new DTO {Id = i}).ToArray();

            //converting
            var arrayResult = Mapper.Map<NumberBase[]>(arrayDto);

            //output
            foreach (var resultElement in arrayResult)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{resultElement.IdOnlyInDestination} - {resultElement.GetType().Name}");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class DTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int EvenFactor => Id%2;
    }

    public abstract class NumberBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int IdOnlyInDestination { get; set; }
    }

    public class OddNumber : NumberBase
    {
        public int EvenFactor { get; set; }
    }

    public class EvenNumber : NumberBase
    {
        public string EventFactor { get; set; }
    }
}
```