# Automapper and implementation of Dtos in the service layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, dto

I am creating a Ntier solution which includes Domain Objects, DataAccess Layer,Service layer and the web API layer . I am using AutoMapper to map Dtos and domain objects in the service layer. I would like to know how to write the logic for performing CRUD operations in the service layer. I have written some mapping. Is this the right way of mapping or is there a better way to do it and also please do correct me where I have written the get, save, update, delete operation. I basically need help in implementing my Service layer.

I am getting the following error when I debug the code:

> Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.

I get the error at the following line of code in the GetPatient method:

```
yield return Mapper.Map<PatientDto>(patient);
```

**Domain layer**

```
public class Patient : BaseEntity
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        public char Gender { get; set; }

        public string Phone { get; set; }
  }
```

**DataAccess Layer**

```
   public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        #region Private member variables...
        internal AppointmentBookingContext Context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;
        #endregion

        #region Public Constructor...
        /// <summary>
        /// Public Constructor,initializes privately declared local variables.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        public GenericRepository(AppointmentBookingContext context)
        {
            this.Context = context;
            this.DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public member methods...

        /// <summary>
        /// generic Get method for Entities
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get()
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;
            return query.ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generic get method on the basis of id for Entities.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
        {
            return DbSet.Find(id);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// generic Insert method for the entities
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"></param>
        public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generic Delete method for the entities
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        public virtual void Delete(object id)
        {
            TEntity entityToDelete = DbSet.Find(id);
            Delete(entityToDelete);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generic Delete method for the entities
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entityToDelete"></param>
        public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
        {
            if (Context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                DbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
            }
            DbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generic update method for the entities
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entityToUpdate"></param>
        public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// generic method to get many record on the basis of a condition.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="where"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetMany(Func<TEntity, bool> where)
        {
            return DbSet.Where(where).ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// generic method to get many record on the basis of a condition but query able.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="where"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetManyQueryable(Func<TEntity, bool> where)
        {
            return DbSet.Where(where).AsQueryable();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// generic get method , fetches data for the entities on the basis of condition.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="where"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public TEntity Get(Func<TEntity, Boolean> where)
        {
            return DbSet.Where(where).FirstOrDefault<TEntity>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// generic delete method , deletes data for the entities on the basis of condition.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="where"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void Delete(Func<TEntity, Boolean> where)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> objects = DbSet.Where<TEntity>(where).AsQueryable();
            foreach (TEntity obj in objects)
                DbSet.Remove(obj);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// generic method to fetch all the records from db
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return DbSet.ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Inclue multiple
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="predicate"></param>
        /// <param name="include"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetWithInclude(
            System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity,
            bool>> predicate, params string[] include)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.DbSet;
            query = include.Aggregate(query, (current, inc) => current.Include(inc));
            return query.Where(predicate);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generic method to check if entity exists
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="primaryKey"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool Exists(object primaryKey)
        {
            return DbSet.Find(primaryKey) != null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a single record by the specified criteria (usually the unique identifier)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="predicate">Criteria to match on</param>
        /// <returns>A single record that matches the specified criteria</returns>
        public TEntity GetSingle(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
        {
            return DbSet.Single<TEntity>(predicate);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The first record matching the specified criteria
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="predicate">Criteria to match on</param>
        /// <returns>A single record containing the first record matching the specified criteria</returns>
        public TEntity GetFirst(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate)
        {
            return DbSet.First<TEntity>(predicate);
        }


        #endregion
    }
```

**Service layer**

**PatientDto.cs**

```
 public class PatientDto
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        public char Gender { get; set; }

        public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

**AutoMapperConfiguration.cs**

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
           Assembly[] assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().OfType<Assembly>().ToArray();
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        cfg.AddProfiles(AllClasses.FromAssemblies(assemblies)
        .Where(
        a =>
           a.FullName.EndsWith("Mapping"))));        }
}
```

**DomainToDtoMapping.cs**

```
   public class DomainToDtoMapping : Profile
    {

        public DomainToDtoMapping()
        {
          CreateMap<BaseEntity, BaseDto>().ReverseMap();
          CreateMap<Patient, PatientDto>().ReverseMap();

         }
}
```

**IPatientService**

```
   public interface IPatientService
    {
        IEnumerable<PatientDto> GetPatient();
        PatientDto GetPatientById(int id);
        int CreatePatient(PatientDto customer);
        bool UpdatePatient(PatientDto patient);
        bool DeletePatient(int patient);

    }
```

**PatientService**

```
public class PatientService : IPatientService
    {

        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;


public int CreatePatient(PatientDto patientDto)
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            var patient = _unitOfWork.PatientRepository.GetByID(patientDto.Id);

            _unitOfWork.PatientRepository.Insert(patient);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            scope.Complete();
            return patient.Id;
        }
    }

    public bool DeletePatient(int id)
    {
        var success = false;

        if (id > 0)
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                var patient = _unitOfWork.PatientRepository.GetByID(id);
                if (patient != null)
                {

                    _unitOfWork.PatientRepository.Delete(patient);
                    _unitOfWork.Save();
                    scope.Complete();
                    success = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<PatientDto> GetPatient()
    {
        var patient = _unitOfWork.PatientRepository.GetAll();
        if (patient != null)
        {
            yield return Mapper.Map<PatientDto>(patient);
        }
        yield return null;
    }

    public PatientDto GetPatientById(int id)
    {
        var patient = _unitOfWork.PatientRepository.GetByID(id);
        if (patient != null)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<PatientDto>(patient);
        }
        return null;

    }

    public bool UpdatePatient(PatientDto patientDto)
    {
        var success = false;

        if (patientDto != null)
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                var patient = _unitOfWork.PatientRepository.GetByID(patientDto.Id);

                if (patient != null)
                {

                    _unitOfWork.PatientRepository.Update(patient);
                    _unitOfWork.Save();
                    scope.Complete();
                    success = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return success;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Seems pretty neat. Are you using any dependency injection framework? I'm considering that all those classes are in separete files.

Comment: Yes Carlos. I am using Unity.MVC5. Each layer is separate project . The patientservice controller is in a separate file

Comment: Where are you calling AutoMapperConfiguration?

Comment: AutoMapperConfiguration.cs. I have updated the post to show you that they are different files.

Comment: Good. But you are initializing AutoMapperConfiguration in your dependency injection registration class? The only improvement I can see, is to use AddProfiles method instead of AddProfile. This way, you would dinamically add profile classes that exists in your solution, without manually adding it to AutoMapperConfiguration class. But in your organization, everything seems fine. Are your Interfaces in a separete project?

Comment: I have updated the post. Yes the interfaces are in a different class. I didnt understand when you say you are initializing AutoMapperConfiguration in your dependency injection registration class? There is no dependency injection in the AutoMapperConfiguration class. I have set dependency injection unity in wep api layer which I havent shared in this post. Also I didnt get the  use AddProfiles method. Could you explain a bit more. Probably showing examples relevant to my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131525/discussion-between-tom-and-carlos-crespo).

Comment: I am getting the following error when I debug the code.  Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.   I get the error at the following line of code in the GetPatient method  yield return Mapper.Map<PatientDto>(patient);

Comment: Are you calling the Configure method of the AutoMapperConfiguration class anywhere in your code?

Comment: no .Where do i call it

Comment: I use to make that call in the same class where I configure unity. But you can call it in global.asax too.

Comment: I added the following line in global.asax  AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure(); but get the following error  Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Comment: You need to put those CreateMap inside the constructor of DomainToDtoMapping . Otherwise they won't be called

Comment: I have moved the createmap to the constructor of DomainToDtoMapping. While debugging ,i do see it getting called but I get the same error

Comment: Do you still have this map there `CreateMap<Patient, PatientDto>()?`?

Comment: Yes I do have. See the updated post. I have moved it to the constructor. I do see getting it called while debugging. It fails at this line of code      yield return Mapper.Map<PatientDto>(patient); in the GetPatient()

Comment: GetAll returns a list. Try iterating through the list of model and build manually a list of dto, mapping each item. Later you can build an extension method to do that for you.

Comment: I think your mapping is wrong.  Because you're using a base class you may need to map like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348634/automapper-and-inheritance-how-to-map

Comment: I have tried to map the base entity. I have updated my post. I still get the same error

Comment: `var patientDto = new List<PatientDto>();
            foreach(var p in patient){
                patientDto.Add(Mapper.Map<PatientDto>(p));
            }

            yield return patientDto;`

Comment: I have added the code. I get the following compile error on the return statement  cannot implicitly convert type System.Collection.Generic.List<AppointmentBooking.Service.Dtos.PatientDto> to AppointmentBooking.Service.Dtos.PatientDto

Comment: @Tom, have you changed GetPatient method or GetPatientById? The code I've posted is for GetPatient, which returns a List of PatientDto.

Comment: GetPatient method which returns  IEnumerable<PatientDto>

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is the "yield". Yield returns are designed to return single instances of an object as the IEnumerable is enumerated over. You're trying to return an entire List there. If you remove the yield, or move it up into your foreach (returning the PatientDTO rather than adding it to a List) then it should work.

Comment: Hi Necoras, I tried the first option that you suggested i.e remove the yield. It gives me an error message .Cannot return value from the iterator. Use the yield return statement to return the value. I didn't understand the second option. Are you saying move the return statement to foreach as is. I still see the same error message. Can you show me an example

Comment: He meant this: `foreach(var p in patient){
    yield return Mapper.Map<PatientDTO>(p);
}`. then you can remove all List<PatientDTO> stuff. Also, Instead of `yield return null`, it is a better practice to return an empty enumerable: `yield return Enumerable.Empty<PatientDTO>()`

Comment: Thanks Carlos. The outer return statement doesnt work i.e yield return Enumerable.Empty<PatientDTO>(). I get the same error message  as I mentioned in the post.

Comment: try `yield break` then

Comment: Have you already looked at ExpressMapper?

Comment: Any updates on this problem? I facing same issue too.