# AutoMapperConfigurationException: Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am getting this error and I do not understand why. I am trying to map a Client object to a ClaimClient object (shown below):

```
public class ClaimClient : Client
    {
        public int ClaimClientID { get; set; }
        public bool IsContactable { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see the ClaimClient will contain all the client properties plus the additional properties shown above. My mapper:

```
x.CreateMap<Client, ClaimClient>();
```

The only thing I can think of is it's expecting me to define a mapping between Client and Client? Any help appreciated

EDIT:

Mapper now as below but still getting same error:

```
x.CreateMap<Client, ClaimClient>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Title, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Title))
                .ForPath(dest => dest.pAddress, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.pAddress))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.IsLead, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IsLead))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.HasOptions, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.HasOptions))
                .ForPath(dest => dest.Options, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Options));


                x.CreateMap<Client, Client>();
```

Comment: Maybe you use an older version. Because the message continues with "You can use ForPath, a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead."

Comment: So you think I should use ForPath for client -> client? I have never seen before where the exact same type must be mapped

Comment: I have read the above documentation but fail to see how it applies here - I've updated my mapper as shown above and am still getting the same error

Comment: Maybe try something like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348634/automapper-and-inheritance-how-to-map)